# HowTo redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the same httpd?

Tags: centos, redirect, httpd

Here is what I have got:

- CentOS 5.4 (32-bit)
- installed Apache httpd (Server version: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix))
- mod_rewrite already presents

Question: how to redirect simple http://site.com to https://site.com **not** using VirtualHost defines?

PS: tried to find in later answers on SF, but doesn't find nice solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1` makes more sense to me.

Comment: Won't that infinite loop on you?

Comment: Nope, just tested it. It's even how it's [advised under the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) - look at the end of it.

Comment: I get an infinite loop using Apache 2.4.10, deploying on Heroku, when I insert those commands into my .htaccess.  And the variant suggested by Cawas oddly mangles my URL.  I've tried a different set of commands:  `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` and `RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}` -- which works on Chrome and Firefox, but fails on Safari and Opera.  Interestingly, if I take the three lines above and omit `RewriteEngine On` I no longer get the infinite loop, but it still fails in Safari and Opera (and works in Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

You can use mod_alias and [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) based on directory.  The linked document identifies additional details.

```
<Directory /path/to/site>
   Redirect /service https://foo2.example.com/service 
</Directory>
```